# Android: Use GestureDetector and Zoomy at the same time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zooming, uigesturerecognizer

I use a GestureListener on an image to detect a Double Tap.

```
            holder.image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return holder.myDoubleTapDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
```

And I use the library [Zoomy](https://github.com/imablanco/Zoomy) to make the images zoomable.

```
            Zoomy.Builder builder = new Zoomy.Builder(mActivity).target(holder.image);
            builder.register();
```

Both work perfectly fine for them alone.

But adding both at the same time does **not** work! Only the one that was added last works.

How can I have both of them working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoomy provides a solution for that:

> Because Zoomy works by attaching a View.OnTouchListener to the registered View, View.OnClickListener can not be set along with Zoomy, so a TapListener, LongPressListener and DoubleTapListener are provided to ensure the View still can listen for gestures. A ZoomListener is also provided if you are interested in zoom events.

In Code:

```
Zoomy.Builder builder = new Zoomy.Builder(this)
                    .target(mZoomableView)
                    .tapListener(new TapListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTap(View v) {
                            //View tapped, do stuff
                        }
                    })
                     .longPressListener(new LongPressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLongPress(View v) {
                            //View long pressed, do stuff
                        }
                    }).doubleTapListener(new DoubleTapListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDoubleTap(View v) {
                            //View double tapped, do stuff
                        }
                    })
                    .zoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onViewStartedZooming(View view) {
                            //View started zooming
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onViewEndedZooming(View view) {
                            //View ended zooming
                        }
                    });
```